# How To search for user across all domains?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a Powershell script to get password expiry for specific set of users. These users belongs to different domains (across the world) in our org.

I use `Get-Aduser` to get the do this. The script works only for users where the script is run from. So if the script is run from let's say US, the `Get-AdUser` finds only users from US.

How can I search across all domains?

I tried this

```
Get-AdUser -Server <GlobalCatalog> [...]
```

This does have the same result without `-Server`

Comment: Try including the Global Catalog port in your command `Get-AdUser -Server GlobalCatalogServer.contoso.com:3268`

Comment: I did that and still same result. It only search the use under the domain where the script is run.

Comment: with -Server it always search `under: 'DC=subdomain,DC=company,DC=com'`

Comment: Is the GC you're using listed when running: `Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service GlobalCatalog`

Comment: No. I see only one host name.

Comment: You need to have a chat with your AD Team to check you have the appropriate permissions (and use the correct servers) for this task.

Comment: thanks..will try to find the responsible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the following:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(yourFilterCondition)} -SearchBase "" -Server X.Y.Z.W:3268 -Properties desiredProperties | select-object...
```

Setting `SearchBase` to "" is the key thing here. And, also try to perform the query on 3268 port for reading values from all domains.

Comment: What should I provide in `-searchbase` ? I tried giving `-searchbase "dc=company,dc=com"` omitting the `dc=domain` but the same result. The port isn't an issue in  my case as I provide the sever with the port.

Comment: @KK99 - Searchbase should be set to empty `-SearchBase ""` as shown in my answer, and you need to query on port number 3268. Check whether this helps.

Comment: Adding this `-SearchBase ""` results in the error `Get-ADUser : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`

Comment: @KK99 - Did you include the Server port 3268 in the LDAP query? Can you post the complete line what you're executing? It's hard for me to believe that it'd throw this type of error.

Comment: `Get-ADUser -identity "user" -SearchBase "" -Server "a.b.c:3268" -Properties PasswordLastSet | select PasswordLastSet`

Comment: @KK99 - It seems you didn't check the syntax for `Get-ADUser`; SearchBase only applies when you apply the Filter condition. If you'll check my answer, I have shown a filterCondition in the script. Check the official link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164554/discussion-between-am-i-helpful-and-kk99).

Comment: Let me have a look once again at the doc. Sorry chat is blocked :(

Comment: Think I got it working after applying -filter. Thank you.

Comment: @KK99 - You're welcome KK99, you can also put the filter for `-Filter {(Enabled -eq 'True')}`, apart from other filters, in this code to have it working. Good Luck...