# Find users and groups in all domains of my organization

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need help finding users/groups that fall under multiple domains in my organization. As I have it right now it only looks through the main domain. I would want it to search for users/groups in all of my organizations domains.

This is what I have:

```
$Users = @()
$Groups = @()
$list = Get-Content C:\temp\ADGroups.txt
Foreach ($o in $list){
$ObjectClass = (Get-ADObject -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $o}).ObjectClass
   If ($ObjectClass -eq "User")
   {
   $U = Get-ADUser -Properties * -Identity $o
   $User = "" | Select FullUserName, LoginID, Description
   $User.FullUserName = $U.DisplayName
   $User.LoginID = $U.SamAccountName
   $User.Description = $U.description
   $Users += $User
   }
  Else
  {
  If ($ObjectClass -eq "Group")
  {
  $G = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Identity $o
  $GM = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $G.name -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties *
  Foreach ($gmember in $GM)
  {
  $Group = "" | Select GroupName, GroupDescription, GroupMemberName, GroupMemberLoginID, GroupMemberDesc
  $Group.GroupName = $G.Name
  $Group.GroupDescription = $G.Description
  $Group.GroupMemberName = $gmember.Name
  $Group.GroupMemberLoginID = $gmember.SamAccountName
  $Group.GroupMemberDesc = $gmember.Description
  $Groups += $Group 
  }
   }
    }
     }
>> $Users | Export-Csv C:\temp\PCMUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
>> $Groups | Export-Csv C:\temp\PCMGroups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Use `Get-ADForest`, go through each domain in `Domains` and grab the `Get-ADDomain <domain>).PDCEmulator`.  Then query for the user, passing the `-Server` parameter.  Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of *TheIncorrigible1* comment, here is some code to accompany which may be useful.

```
$Domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains.ForEach{(Get-ADDomain $_).PDCEmulator}

$Users = @()
$Groups = @()
$list = Get-Content C:\temp\ADGroups.txt


ForEach ($dom in $Domains) {
    Foreach ($o in $list){
        $ObjectClass = (Get-ADObject -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $o}).ObjectClass

            #Gets the users in that directory according to the ObjectClass rules 
            Get-ADUser -Identity $ObjectClass -Server $dom -Properties * 
            #....
    }
}

#....
#....
```

Note: I don't have the AD-Module installed so I couldn't test it. let me know if it fails

Comment: You could simplify your domain gathering: `$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains.ForEach{(Get-ADDomain $_).PDCEmulator}`

Comment: @GNUzilla This is the error I'm getting :

'Get-ADUser : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:11 char:8
+   $U = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server $dom -Properties * -Identity $o
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser'

Comment: ok I think I fixed it. I was using 2 conflicting required parameters

Comment: its still ignoring the other domains @GNUzilla

Comment: @ramonster - Please check if [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48620291/3482140) can be anywhere helpful to you!

Comment: Wouldn't searching the global catalog be faster and easier?

Comment: @GNUzilla Still no luck

Comment: Got it to work but now I'm getting a different error. Get-ADUser : A referral was returned from the server
At line:25 char:70
+ ... -Identity $G.name -Recursive | Get-ADUser  -Server $dom -Properties *
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: